# Close modal in ajaxStop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 var menuButtonClick = {
        onReady: function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.menu-button', function () {
                menuButtonClick.clickedButton($(this).html());
            });
        },

        clickedButton: function (val) {
            switch (val) {
                    case 'CheckModelBank':
                        modelBankHandler.get();
                        break;
                }
        }
    }

    var modelBankHandler = (function () {
    var get = function () {

        var selectedCellData = handsonTable.selectedCellData.get();
        var webGrid = handsonTable.WebGrid.get();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:56292/api/Data/CheckModelBank",
            data: { "": selectedCellData },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    serverResult = JSON.parse(response);

                    printModelBank(serverResult, webGrid);

                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (textStatus == "error") {
                    modalHandler.printErrorModal();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var printModelBank = function (serverResult, webGrid) {
       ///
    }

    return {
        get: get
    }

})();


    var fileHandler = {
        onReady: function () {
            var documentType = "";

            $('.upload-file').click(function () {
                $('[data-remodal-id=documentModal]').remodal().open();
            });

            $('.document-option').click(function () {
                //Need to get the type of document the user is going to work with so we can parse the document correctly to the webgrid
                documentType = $(this).html();
                $('#fileUpload').click();
            });

            $('#fileUpload').change(function () {
                fileHandler.upload(documentType);
            });

            $('.save-to-excell').click(fileHandler.saveDocument);
        },

        upload: function (documentType) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                var file = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[i];
                formData.append("fileUpload", file);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:59973/Home/Upload',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    jsonData = JSON.parse(response.data);
                    if (jsonData != null) {
                        if (documentType == "Infolog") {
                            fileHandler.printDocument(jsonData); //This is used for pickinglist and infolog
                        } else {
                            var webGrid = handsonTable.WebGrid.get();
                            webGrid.loadData(jsonData);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    if (textStatus == "error") {
                        modalHandler.printErrorModal();
                    }
                }
            });
        },
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        handsonTable.init();

        menuButtonClick.onReady();
        fileHandler.onReady();
        buttonClicks.onReady();

    }).ajaxStart(function () {
            $('[data-remodal-id=modalAjax]').remodal().open();
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $('[data-remodal-id=modalAjax]').remodal().close();
        });
```

When I upload a file (fileHandler), the modal shows during ajaxStart and closes on ajaxStop. However, If I click on a button in my menu (menuButtonclick) which trigger my modelBankHandler function, the modal shows during ajaxstart, but does not close on ajaxStop.

Why? All the data are retrieved as expected in my modelBankHandler, so why does not the modal closes?

Answer (score 0):

If you have pressed F12 in the browser and looked at the console you would probably have found an error there. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4q86IjJFag) might help you to figure out basic problems yourelf.

I think `printModelBank` might throw an error, if the success or error functions throw an error then jQuery crashes and does not execute the `ajaxStop` handler:

```
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
  console.log("open model");
}).ajaxStop(function () {
  console.log("close model");
});
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/none",
  data: {},
  success: function (response) {
    console.log("success");
    throw new Error("now stop won't execute");
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("error");
    throw new Error("now stop won't execute");
  }
});
```

You could solve this by having success and error as promise handlers, errors in promise handlers should not crash jQuery (but it does):

```
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
  console.log("open model");
}).ajaxStop(function () {
  console.log("close model");
});
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/none",
  data: {}
})
.then(
  response => {
    console.log("success");
    throw new Error("now stop won't execute");
  },
  (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
    console.log("error");
    throw new Error("now stop won't execute");
  }
);
```

You could try native promises (jQuery still doesn't get promises right) and have it not crash on error in handler:

```
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
  console.log("open model");
}).ajaxStop(function () {
  console.log("close model");
});

Promise.resolve()
.then(_ =>
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/none",
    data: {}
  })  
)
.then(
  response => {
    console.log("success");
    throw new Error("now stop WILL execute");
  },
  (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
    console.log("error");
    throw new Error("now stop WILL execute");
  }
);
```

IE does not support [native promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you will need a [polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) or try babel with ES2016

Comment: No, I don't get any errors. The funny thing is that when the response data back from the server to the client contains more than 4 rows, it works. But when It contains 4 rows or less, it does not work. The modal does not close when the result data contains 4 rows or less of data.

Comment: I think the probolem is the remodal-plugin. If I replace the modal with just a regular div, it works. The div is displayed and hided as expected in ajaxStart and ajaxStop.

Comment: @Bryan so if you put a console log in the `ajaxStop` (before doing anything else) handler then you can see the log? If not then there probably is some error. Maybe jQuery swallows it and it won't show in the console.

Comment: As I said, i have no error. I have put console.log everywhere, and no error occurs. I solved It by setting a setTimeout in the ajaxStop.